# Update foreign key on INSERT INTO... SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following statement to insert values from one table (posts) into another (conversations):

```
INSERT INTO conversations (subject, user_id, notify_me, invite_only, real_name_only, max_post_length, last_updated_at, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT subject, user_id, notify_me, invite_only, real_name_only, max_post_length, thread_updated_at, created_at, updated_at FROM posts WHERE ancestry IS null;
```

After each insert, I want to update the `conversation_id` column of `posts` to point to the newly inserted `conversations` row.

What's the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: This query will insert multiple rows. The posts look to be a child of conversations so why would you not have the id of conversation that the post is about.

Comment: This is part of a database migration. I'm creating the table conversations, then moving relevant data from posts to conversations, then trying to establish a relationship between them by setting conversation_id on posts.

Comment: Then just loop through the result set and use the LAST_INSERT_ID() to update the posts. If you are trying to go through a conversion, then disable the identity column in conversation. Update posts.conversation_id using update statement and then restore identity. Looks like u r trying too hard...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Not sure about mysql language but it works something like this select max(id)+1 from conversation into :my_max  for loop ; update post set conversation_id= my_max ;  insert into conversation(id, ) select my_max, ... ; my_max++ ; end loop.. sorry about syntax

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a trigger :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT ON `conversations` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE posts
        SET posts.conversation_id = NEW.Id
        WHERE
            posts.subject = NEW.subject
            AND posts.user_id = NEW.user_id
            AND posts.created_at = NEW.created_at;
END$$
```

Comment: `Can't update table 'posts' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`